# Envio de emails que pertencem a um grupo

Tags: sql, asp

Preciso de uma ajuda, estou desenvolvendo um sistema de mailing que possibita o envio para um conjunto de e-mail que pertencem a um grupo, eu consegui fazer uma parte agora, o meu campo txt_para deve receber o nome de um grupo qualquer e dentro deste grupo, preciso fazer meu ASP ler os e-mails que fazem parte deste grupo e o grupo todo receber este mesmo e-mail, segue primeiramente as tables envolvidas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da página envia_Email.asp que recebe os dados do formulário anterior, ele envia para uma massa de e-mail, por exemplo a@a.com, b@a.com, mas não estou conseguindo para um grupo por exemplo:

```
If request("btEnviar") = "Enviar" Then

    'Requests
    v_id_Email_Remet        = request("txtidEmailRem")

    Sql_Id = "SELECT" & _
               " Id_Email" & _
               ", Email_Endereco" & _
           " FROM" & _
               " Email" & _
           " WHERE" & _
               " Id_Email = '" & v_id_Email_Remet & "'"

    Set rsDados = Cn.Execute(Sql_Id)

    if rsDados.eof  Then
        Response.Redirect caminhoASP & "mensagem.asp?msg=" & err.Description
    else
        v_Email_Remet = rsDados("Email_Endereco")
    End If

    v_Assunto               = request("txtAssunto")
    v_Destinatario          = trim(request("txtPara"))
    v_Copia                 = request("txtCopia")
    v_Template              = request("slc_template")
    v_Mensagem              = request("txtarea_Mensagem")
    v_ModeloEnvio           = request("rad_ModeloEnvio")

    Response.Write "Destinatario: " & v_Destinatario & "<br>"

    v_Corpo = "Email enviado de: " & v_Email_Remet & " Para " & v_Destinatario & ", " & " Assunto: " & v_Assunto & " , " & " Mensagem: " & v_Mensagem

    'Response.Write ("<b> Id</b> " & v_Email_Remet & "<b> Assunto</b> " & v_Assunto & "<b> Para</b> " & v_Destinatario & "<b> Copia</b> " & v_Copia & "<b> Template</b> " & v_Template & "<b> Mensagem</b> " & v_Mensagem & "<b> Modelo</b> " & v_ModeloEnvio)
    'Response.End

    arr_email = split(v_Destinatario, ",")


    for i = 0 to UBound(arr_email)


            if InStr(1,arr_email(i),"@") > 1 then
                v_Cdosys = EnviaEmail_CDOSYS (v_Email_Remet,arr_email(i),v_Assunto,v_Corpo,"")
                if v_Cdosys = 0 then
                    v_msgMensagem = "E-mail enviado com sucesso."
                    v_MostraInfo = v_msgMensagem
                end if
            else

                grupo_id = " SELECT " & _
                           " Id_Grupo" & _
                           " FROM Grupo" & _
                           " WHERE" & _
                           " Grupo_Nome = '" & arr_email(i) & "'"

                Call AbreRS(grupo_id)

                While Not Rs.EOF

                    v_IdGrupo = Rs("Id_Grupo")

                Rs.MoveNext
                Wend
                Call FechaRS

                 Response.Write "Primeira parte Id Grupo " & v_IdGrupo & "<br>"


                    if IsNumeric(v_IdGrupo) then


                            arr_grupoemail = " SELECT " & _
                                             " b.Email_Endereco " & _
                                             " FROM Grupo_Email a " & _
                                             " INNER JOIN Email b ON a.Id_Email = b.Id_Email " & _
                                             " WHERE " & _
                                             " a.Id_Grupo = '" & v_IdGrupo & "'"


                            Response.Write "Query " & arr_grupoemail & "<br>"

                        Call AbreRS(arr_grupoemail)

                        While Not Rs.EOF

                            'array_GrupoEmail = array_GrupoEmail & "," & Rs("Email_Endereco")
                            array_GrupoEmail = array_GrupoEmail & Rs("Email_Endereco")
                        Rs.MoveNext
                        Wend
                        Call FechaRS    

                        'limpa = replace(array_GrupoEmail,",","")
                        Response.Write "Valores " & array_GrupoEmail

                        item = split(array_GrupoEmail, ",")
                        Response.Write "Final " & item
                        'Response.End()

                                     for j = 0 to UBound(item)
                                       v_Cdosys = EnviaEmail_CDOSYS (v_Email_Remet,item(j),v_Assunto,v_Corpo,"")
                                        if v_Cdosys = 0 then
                                             v_msgMensagem = "E-mail enviado com sucesso."
                                             v_MostraInfo = v_msgMensagem
                                        end if
                                     next

                    else
                                 v_msgMensagem = "Não é um grupo"
                                 v_MostraInfo  = v_msgMensagem
                    end if

            end if

    next
End If
```

O erro que persiste é abaixo nos request de retorno:

> Destinatario: Desenvolvimento Primeira parte Id Grupo 1 Query SELECT
>   b.Email_Endereco FROM Grupo_Email a INNER JOIN Email b ON a.Id_Email =
>   b.Id_Email WHERE a.Id_Grupo = '1' Valores
>   leandro@dominio.comleonardo@dominio.com
>
> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
>
> Type mismatch
>
> /iom/Sistemas/Mailing/ASP/envia_Email.asp, line 121

Nesta linha do `response.write` após o `split`:

```
item = split(array_GrupoEmail, ",")
Response.Write "Final " & item
```

Não sei muito o que fazer para faze-lo enviar, gostaria da ajuda de vcs, obrigado

Comment: a primeira coisa a fazer é debugar essa linha, da um response.write item e responde.end. Ve se tem alguma aspa que está quebrando o codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quero compartilhar com vocês a minha solução encontrada 2 meses atrás, o envio de e-mail em massa, incluindo no campo Para o nome do Grupo já esta funcionando, espero ajudar a quem precise algum dia, segue abaixo o código completo do arquivo envia_email.asp

```
If request("btEnviar") = "Enviar" Then

'Requests
v_id_Email_Remet        = request("txtidEmailRem")

Sql_Id = "SELECT" & _
           " Id_Email" & _
           ", Email_Endereco" & _
       " FROM" & _
           " Email" & _
       " WHERE" & _
           " Id_Email = '" & v_id_Email_Remet & "'"

Set rsDados = Cn.Execute(Sql_Id)

if rsDados.eof  Then
    Response.Redirect caminhoASP & "mensagem.asp?msg=" & err.Description
else
    v_Email_Remet = rsDados("Email_Endereco")
End If

v_Assunto               = request("txtAssunto")
v_Destinatario          = trim(request("txtPara"))
v_Copia                 = request("txtCopia")
v_Template              = request("slc_template")
v_Mensagem              = request("txtarea_Mensagem")
v_ModeloEnvio           = request("rad_ModeloEnvio")

Response.Write "Destinatario: " & v_Destinatario & "<br>"

v_Corpo = "Email enviado de: " & v_Email_Remet & " Para " & v_Destinatario & ", " & " Assunto: " & v_Assunto & " , " & " Mensagem: " & v_Mensagem

'Response.Write ("<b> Id</b> " & v_Email_Remet & "<b> Assunto</b> " & v_Assunto & "<b> Para</b> " & v_Destinatario & "<b> Copia</b> " & v_Copia & "<b> Template</b> " & v_Template & "<b> Mensagem</b> " & v_Mensagem & "<b> Modelo</b> " & v_ModeloEnvio)
'Response.End

arr_email = split(v_Destinatario, ",")


for i = 0 to UBound(arr_email)


        if InStr(1,arr_email(i),"@") > 1 then
            v_Cdosys = EnviaEmail_CDOSYS (v_Email_Remet,arr_email(i),v_Assunto,v_Corpo,"")
            if v_Cdosys = 0 then
                v_msgMensagem = "E-mail enviado com sucesso."
                v_MostraInfo = v_msgMensagem
            end if
        else

            grupo_id = " SELECT " & _
                       " Id_Grupo" & _
                       " FROM Grupo" & _
                       " WHERE" & _
                       " Grupo_Nome = '" & arr_email(i) & "'"

            Call AbreRS(grupo_id)

            While Not Rs.EOF

                v_IdGrupo = Rs("Id_Grupo")

            Rs.MoveNext
            Wend
            Call FechaRS

             Response.Write "Primeira parte Id Grupo " & v_IdGrupo & "<br>"


                if IsNumeric(v_IdGrupo) then


                        arr_grupoemail = " SELECT " & _
                                         " b.Email_Endereco " & _
                                         " FROM Grupo_Email a " & _
                                         " INNER JOIN Email b ON a.Id_Email = b.Id_Email " & _
                                         " WHERE " & _
                                         " a.Id_Grupo = '" & v_IdGrupo & "'"


                        Response.Write "Query " & arr_grupoemail & "<br>"

                    Call AbreRS(arr_grupoemail)

                    While Not Rs.EOF

                        'array_GrupoEmail = array_GrupoEmail & "," & Rs("Email_Endereco")
                        array_GrupoEmail = array_GrupoEmail & Rs("Email_Endereco")

                        if array_GrupoEmail <> "" then
                            array_GrupoEmail = array_GrupoEmail  & ","
                        end if

                    Rs.MoveNext
                    Wend
                    Call FechaRS

                    Response.Write "Valores " & array_GrupoEmail

                    emails_porgrupo = split(array_GrupoEmail, ",")

                    'Response.Write "Final " & emails_porgrupo

                                 for j = 0 to UBound(emails_porgrupo)
                                    if InStr(1,emails_porgrupo(j),"@") > 1 then 
                                       v_Cdosys = EnviaEmail_CDOSYS (v_Email_Remet,emails_porgrupo(j),v_Assunto,v_Corpo,"")
                                        if v_Cdosys = 0 then
                                             v_msgMensagem = "E-mail enviado com sucesso."
                                             v_MostraInfo = v_msgMensagem
                                        end if
                                    end if
                                 next

                else
                             v_msgMensagem = "Não é um grupo"
                             v_MostraInfo  = v_msgMensagem
                end if

        end if

next
```

End If